# "I wonder what to start work on" - does it sound fine?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

For example, I'm looking for a task to work on, is it fine to say it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I wonder what to start work on

This suggests you could possibly begin work on a desk or something similar.

> I wonder what to start **working** on

This means there is something (a project for example) on which you would like to work.

As it stands, the latter is more appropriate in your case.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: Thank you for help